# how to merge multiple dataframe in a loop by using classes

Tags: pandas, function, class, inheritance

Uses class and define functions to do pd.merge between multiple dataframes.
Error shown.

I tried this, shown:

```
ValueError:can not merge DataFrame with instance of type 
<class '__main__.Merge'>
```

```
class Merge(object):
    def __init__(self, table1, table2):
        self.table1 = table1
        self.table2 = table2
    def merged(self):
        return pd.merge(self.table1,self.table2, how ='left', on ='TITLE')
a=Merge(df4,df6);b=Merge(a,df8);c=Merge(b,df10);d=Merge(c,df12);e=Merge(d,df14);f=Merge(e,df16)
for obj in [a,b,c,d,e,f]:
    obj.merged()
```

Is it possible to use class in order to loop them and loop everything in one go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this accomplish what you need ?

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

class Merge(object):
    def __init__(self, tables, on, how):
        self.tables = tables
        self.on = on
        self.how = left


    def merged(self):
        return reduce(
            lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=self.on, how=self.how), self.tables
        )


obj = Merge(tables=[df1, df2, df3], on="TITLE", how="left")
obj.merged()
```